# How to run a Elixir file with phoenix stack

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to the elixir ecosystem. I have a import script in my Elixir/Phoenix app and when I try to run it from the command line it does not work because the phoenix stack is not being loaded with my command.

Here is what I'm trying to run:

```
elixir lib/mix/tasks/import/users.ex
```

and I get: `** (CompileError) lib/mix/tasks/import/users.ex:7: module Mix.Ecto is not loaded and could not be found`

Is there a way to tell my command to load the stack?

and here is my users.ex import

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Import.Users do
  @moduledoc """
    Import predefined users.
  """

  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto
  alias App.Shield.Resources.User

  @shortdoc "Import users"
  def run(args) do
    repos = parse_repo(args)

    Enum.each repos, fn repo ->
      Mix.shell.info "=== User Import (CSV) ==="

      ensure_repo(repo, args)
      ensure_started(repo, [])

      static_path = Application.app_dir(:corsair, "priv/static")

      File.stream!("#{static_path}/User.csv")
      |> CSV.decode(headers: true)
      |> Task.async_stream(Mix.Tasks.Import.Users, :process_csv_row, [repo])
      |> Enum.to_list()
    end
  end

  def process_csv_row(row, repo) do
    user = %{
      first_name: row["first_name"],
      last_name: row["last_name"],
      email: row["email"]
    }

    changeset = User.registration_on_subdomain_changeset(%User{}, user)

    case repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        Bunt.puts [:color83, "User #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} created"]
      {:error, changeset} ->
        Bunt.puts [:color197, "Problem with #{row["email"]}"]
        IO.inspect changeset.errors
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found in the documentation how to run custom tasks.
In my case the it was.

`mix import.users`

I had tried `mix tasks.import.users` but the tasks keyword is not necessary

Here is the documentation just in case

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/phoenix_mix_tasks.html#creating-our-own-mix-tasks